# The Amazon is huge, but that doesn't mean the oneboxes need to be

Tags: feature-request, chat, design, onebox, amazon

Recently, [animuson was dissatisfied with his clock](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/amazon-obs-are-enormous). Therefore, one of our illustrious members sought out an Amazon link to a clock that would solve all of animuson's needs. And this happened:

[image]

It's huge. Like, screen-shatteringly huge. It even prompted [this message](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1699046#1699046):

> Why are Amazon one-boxes so huge? Someone write up a feature request to decrease their size. Sheesh. *- animuson*

... and [this one](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1699051#1699051):

> why are amazon products one boxed in the first place? *- jmac*

Therefore, we should decrease the size of these helpful thingys. Please?

Comment: gist.io used to have a similar issue if I recall.

Comment: What is that about????

Comment: @Szymon It's a feature within the chat rooms. You can paste a URL into a chat message and depending on the URL, a one-box preview of the URL will appear so you don't have to click out to the link to read the content. We have these for Amazon, Twitter, Trello, and a few other URLs.

Comment: @Hynes this also happens now with [twitter onebox](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7038532#7038532), which renders the onebox useless, nobody wants to see such a huge thing. Any chance to look into it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh wow… well that seems quite… large. I'll pass this along to the team to see what can be done about it.